# Is this a 2D or 1D array in Pascal?

Tags: pascal, pseudocode

Is this Pascalian pseudocode a 2d array or a 1D array?

```
var T: array[1..n, 1..p] of vartype
```

Comment: Which do *you* think it is? Why are you not sure?

Answer (score 1):

It's 2D, the same as

```
var T:array[1..n]of array[1..p]of vartype;
```